# Literature request: Galois representations

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Not really much to say here; I'm looking for an "introductory text" on the theory of Galois representations. I'll be attending a seminar on the local Langlands correspondence for $\text{GL}_2$ next semester and would like to get a head-start on the material.

I've attended courses on algebraic number theory and local class field theory via Lubin-Tate theory, to give you an idea of my background.

Comment: [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/mhaluksengun/galoisrepsem) are some introductory texts mentioned. You should try to search yourself for further references. It is expected from you for the seminar "next semester".

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks! I have Peter Schneider's "Galois Representations and $(\varphi, \Gamma)$-modules" and we'll be reading from Bushnell and Henniart's book on the subject, I'm just shopping around for some more references

Comment: Have a look [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/MSRI/). There are also video lectures!

Comment: @Mathmo123 I already found these on youtube! Am on the third talk so far, Kevin Buzzard's talks are great